# libpng error: IDAT: invalid distance too far back in MAC OSX 10.9

Tags: opencv, libpng

I've installed opencv2.4.9 with `libstdc++` through `brew install opencv` in MAC OSX 10.9.

I try to `imread` an image from INRIA pedestrian database. The problem is that when I use opencv to read the `PNG` format image, I always get this error:
`libpng error: IDAT: invalid distance too far back`

The version of libpng is 1.6.13 which was also installed by `brew install` command.

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem. First, `brew uninstall libpng` and `brew uninstall opencv`. Then, `brew install libpng12` and `brew install --build-from-source --fresh -vd opencv`. In this process, libpng will also be installed. Even though both `libpng` and `libpng12` are installed, opencv will only use  `libpng12`.

I guess the image from INRIA database maybe a little old to `libpng-1.6.13` library. So, we have to use older libpng version, libpng12, to read it.

### Update: 2014.10.29

I found another way to solve this problem. This way is better.
First, `brew edit opencv` and go to the line which contains `depends_on :libpng`. 
Then, press 'i' and switch to edit mode. change  `depends_on :libpng` to `depends_on "libpng12"`. press `:wq` to save.
Finally, `brew install opencv`.

By doing this, opencv will be compiled using `libpng12` instead of `libpng16`.